# SceneKit LookAt constraint not animating smoothly

Tags: ios, swift, scenekit

I am having issue with the animation of animating the look at constraint. I have a scene with multiple objects that can be tapped. Once you tap on an object, the camera's position is updated to be a certain distance from the object and a look at  constraint is applied.

The issue is with the animation of the look at constraint in the SCNTransaction begin and commit block. I set this code to do a look at:

```
// Causes the camera to look at the given target
private func cameraLookAtTarget(target: SCNNode)
{
    let constraint = SCNLookAtConstraint(target: target)
    constraint.gimbalLockEnabled = true
    cameraNode.constraints = [constraint]
}
```

And the block of code where this gets called when the object is tapped:

```
SCNTransaction.begin()
SCNTransaction.setAnimationDuration(CAMERA_ANIMATION_DURATION)
cameraLookAtTarget(target)
SCNTransaction.commit()
```

The animation does a jump first and then animates to look at the object instead of smoothly rotating the camera to look at the new target. I can confirm that it is the look at constraint, since updating the camera position moves it smoothly.

Edit: Basically, its as though the camera is being reset first in the animation and then animating to look at the target. I want the look at constraint to animate from the current object it is looking at to the new target.

I can't figure out the problem. In Unity I can easily get a rotation that is a look rotation, and apply a slerp to it in the update method so that it slowly looks at the object.

Comment: if you turn off the gimbal lock, does it act smoothly?

Comment: @Confused It has no effect on the jumping. It just rotates with a greater degree of freedom.

Comment: Ok. Another idea. Can you create an object that's the permanent target of the camera, a constant "Look at" object, and move that from any target to any new target, thereby causing the camera to look at something new? In 3D terms, this is known as a "target camera", and the more common way to do this. Moving the target is the process of moving the camera's point of attention, rather than swapping out the target for another and hoping a system animates the transition well.

Comment: @Confused Thank you so much. That worked perfectly. A simple solution that didn't need much programming.

Comment: No worries. Here's how to add easing to the movement action: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39690459/how-to-add-a-fadeout-duration-to-a-scnaction ;)

Comment: Perhaps update your answer with the addition of how you finally did it, when you're done coding, so those that follow can find out how to do this. I haven't a clue how to code this, I just know how to do it in 3ds Max and similar apps.